# Error: list index out of range

Tags: python, function, range

the following function is supposed to give you out all the numbers in a list that do correspond to it's index i.e Index 0 = 0, and append this number in a list.

```
def Utility(l):
Total = []
for i in l:
    if i == l[i]:
        Total.append(i)
    else:
        pass
return Total
```

I do get an Error: list index out of range.

Comment: And do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

`for i in l` iterates over the list `l`. So on every iteration you assign an element from the list to `i`.

If you want `for` indexes, you need to use `enumerate`.

```
for idx, ele in enumerate(l):
    # your code
```

enumerate will return the index and the item on every iteration.
Your code can be written such

```
def Utility(l):
Total = []
for idx, ele in enumerate(l):
    if idx == ele:
        Total.append(idx)
```

The else clause is useless and can be removed

Comment: Thank You for your answer!!!! On a side note, how did this simple question get 4x - xD wtf

Comment: I didn't downvote; I can only guess it is simple, and with some effort researching you could find an answer. I appreciate people who comment on their downvotes, so the OP can learn.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the elements of `l`, not iterating over the indices:

```
for i in [5,6,7]:
    print(i)
> 5
> 6
> 7
```

You should use `enumerate`:

```
for i, num in enumerate([5, 6, 7]):
    print(i, num)
> 0 5
> 1 6
> 2 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be :

```
def Utility(l):
  Total = []
  for i in range(len(l)):          #point of interest
    if i == l[i]:
        Total.append(i)
    else:
        pass
  return Total
```

#driver values

```
IN : l = [0,1,4,6]
OUT : [0,1]
```

The fault in your code is that when you do `for i in l`, the `i` value is the elements in `l`, and since those values can be greater than then number of elements in `l`, it will through up an `Error`. Like:

```
l=[5]
for i in l:
   print(i)
   #5
   print(l[i])           #l[5]
   #IndexError: list index out of range
```